# Comparing variance components

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, mixed-model

Say I have **TWO** data sets collected at different times with the same design. I fit a mixed model using in R using lmer

lmer(y ~ (1|A))

to these data sets and get two estimates of $\sigma^2_A$ and $\sigma^2_e$.

What would be a good way to compare $\sigma^2_A$ and $\sigma^2_e$ for these two data sets and obtain a P value for the hypothesis that $\sigma^2_{A1} = \sigma^2_{A2}$? There is obvious shrinkage on these estimates, should I be worried about the differential levels of shrinkage on these estimates and how to account for that?

Thank you for your thoughts and inputs!

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer the first part of your question: "what would be a good way to compare $\sigma_A^2$ and $\sigma_e^2$"? The intraclass-correlation (ICC; see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation)) is the relation of the clusterspecific variance and the total variance. In your random intercepts model the ICC would be $ \frac{\sigma_A^2 }{\sigma_A^2  + \sigma_e^2}$.

---

This measurment can be frequently found in mixed-model literature like the textbook by Raudenbush & Bryk (2002) *Hierarchical Linear Models*.